# How to have multiple providers dependent upon environment?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two different AWS configurations. On a dev laptop, the developer uses a mfa-secured `profile` inside a `shared_credentials_file`.

On jenkins, we export environment variables and then assume a role.

This means that the provider blocks look really different. At the root level, they share the same `backend.tf`.

I know I can have two different roots with different providers, but is there a way so I don't have to duplicate `backend.tf` and other root files?

Comment: Why not create a profile with the same name jenkins machine before running terraform. That way you don't have to change your terraform code.

`aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --profile $PROFILE_NAME
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --profile $PROFILE_NAME
aws configure set aws_session_token $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN --profile $PROFILE_NAME`

Comment: Would provider aliases help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I understood your point, but it is not recommended. Make aws configuration with system environment variables ready before you run terraform commands.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN (optional)
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE (optional)
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

Comment: I am already using env vars on jenkins, but not locally because in automation we assume a role whereas locally we use the dev's creds file. Furthermore, devs would have to export creds and unset after running every run for security reasons because the precedence of env var creds would supercede other means of authentication used by less privileged services. I guess we can have devs assume the role as well but we also use mfa and it would be a process change that would require everyone to be on board

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I think makes most sense is to **place local developers and jenkins automations into two separate environment directories**, each with their own `aws.tf` and backend workspace.

This made sense because developers should not be messing with resources created by automation, and any operations to the jenkins backend should be done by jenkins, otherwise devs could overwrite resources that jenkins put up, and vice versa.